# Multi user profile creation function

Tags: django-models, django-users

I'm django learner and I'm trying to design multiple userprofile system.

I recently saw the `create_profile` function for single userProfile. How can I redesign it to multi user profile creation function?

```
def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile=Student.objects.create(user=kwargs["instance"])

    post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

Comment: What do you mean by multi-user? multiple users can have the same profile? or one user can have multiple profiles?

Comment: as you know signal announces us when a user is creating.and will create a suitable Userprofile as we mention.but if we have for example 2 type of Userprofile how we can create on of them base on their different features?for example Student & Master as Userprofile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two models for each profile type. If you want, have them inherit from a base model but you don't need to.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more fields

class Master(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more fields

myuser = User.objects.get(...)
student = Student.objects.create(user=myuser)
master = Master.objects.create(user=myuse
```